# What other programming languages besides Dart compile to native machine code across many platforms

Tags: dart, cross-platform

I am learning Dart and was wondering if there are many more programming languages that compile to native machine code across many platforms like IOS, Android, Windows, web etc...

Am I correct in assuming that C, C++ and Go compile directly into native machine code rather than being interpreted?
If those languages count, what about languages like Rust that compile to clang, do they count?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer while reading the following articles:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_compile_anywhere
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_run_anywhere
The slogal WOCA is different from WORA, The initial question only applies to those languages using WOCA. This is no definite list but it is a good explanation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).